# Emacs 24 ruby-mode indentation behavior when using iterator such as `each`

Tags: emacs

```
my_array.each do
          # code here
        end
```

I think the best practice should be:

```
my_array.each do
  # code here
end
```

Should add something to my Emacs config file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to me you're using `emacs-snapshot`. By default it uses a new indentation engine that's a bit buggy right now. To revert to the old one evaluate the following Emacs Lisp code:

```
(setq ruby-use-smie nil)
```

And restart `ruby-mode` afterwards. I'll report the bug upstream.

Comment: And yes, I'ms using `emacs-snapshot`

Comment: Btw, this bug was just fixed in the Emacs head, so if you update your Emacs snapshot the indentation will work properly even when using the new SMIE indentation engine.

Comment: Doesn't look like this is fixed in the Aquamacs 3a version of Emacs 24, as I was still seeing this problem until I used the above solution, so thanks!

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! It solved my (not really related) problem too!